# Collaborate on Angular IO project

Tags: angular

I'm starting a new web project using Angular IO and Angular CLI (version 6.0.1). I'm trying to share this project via GitHub with a few collaborators. However, when the project is downloaded from GitHub and anyone tries to serve the project by running

```
ng serve
```

they get the error

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from ...
```

Even if I download the project to a different directory I get the same error. The error can be fixed by running

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

After that running

```
ng serve
```

works as expected. Is this the standard procedure when collaborating on an Angular IO project? How are such projects normally set up for multiple people? Is there a simpler fix than running

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

after each time the project is downloaded? I've looked around the documentation for Angular IO and tried my luck on Google but haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your collaborators could add a dependency on a package/library that you might not have installed yourself.

I'd suggest looking at an npm command that could git pull and install dependencies. Something to your package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
  "pull": "git pull <some stuff> && ng update @angular/cli && npm i",
}
```

then running `npm run pull` from the command line gets you up to date and installed.

Comment: What would I pull if it is just a blank repo. Thanks for any help